# Building a go project with portaudio-go on OS X (+MacPorts)

Tags: go, macports, portaudio

I try to get `portaudio-go` running under Mac OS X 10.8. I installed portaudio via

```
sudo port install portaudio
```

so that now `portaudio.h` is located in `/opt/local/include`. Since the folder is not a default location for header-files, when running

```
go get code.google.com/p/portaudio-go/portaudio
```

I get an error saying that the `portaudio.h` could not be found. Is there something equivalent to `-I /opt/local/include` I could use for go?

/edit: **Answered**

Comment: You'll probably need to download portaudio-go and change the CGOFLAGS in the cgo file.

Comment: As @cthom06 suggested you'll need to add something like // #cgo linux CFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include to the top of the portaudio.go file. You should have a local copy after the `go get` and then you can rebuild with `go build` and `go install` from the directory that portaudio.go was downloaded to. That directory depends on how you've set up your Go environment variables.

Comment: @KevinD If you found a solution, you should write an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the first lines of `portaudio.go`:

```
package portaudio

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/opt/local/lib -lportaudio
```

Now everything works fine, thank you!